# How to pass a GeometryCollection between threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

**My Situation:**

I want to draw a map that consists of different layers.

So far I use an `ItemsControl` to display all of the layers:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LayerViewTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The template i use looks like this:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="LayerViewTemplate"
                 DataType="{x:Type data:InformationLayer}">
       <Path StrokeThikness="{Binding W}"
             Stroke="Black"
             Data = {Binding Data}/>
   </DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, the class `InformationLayer` contains all of the data of one layer. This includes the property:

```
public GeometryGroup Data { get; protected set; }
```

Generating the Layers is a lengthy process tough.
I have to read a bunch of files etc.
That's why I would like to do it in an asynchronous function.

**The Problem:**

GeometryGroup objects belong to the thread that created them.
So if I use a different thread to create my layers, they will belong to that thread.
I want them to belong to my main thread tough, because I want to use them as a binding source.
Is there a possibility to move the GeometryGroup from one thread to the other?

So far, the function to generate my layers looks like this:
but the last line throws an exception, because wpf doesn't want to bind to an object, that has been generated in a different thread.

```
    protected async void generateLayers()
    {
        var progress = new Progress<RefreshLayersProgressReport>(ReportLayerProgress);
        var ans =  await Task.Run(() => refreshLayers(progress));

        Layers = ans;
    }
```

Comment: Thread run a separate process so you need to either pass all the data to the thread at start of thread or use a pipe.  A simple pipe can be used with a MemoryStream class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GeometryGroup` is derived from `Freezable`. So it should be cross-thread accessible after calling its `Freeze()` method.

From the **Thread Safety** section on the [Freezable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable(v=vs.110).aspx) page:

> When the IsFrozen property is false, a Freezable object can be
>   accessed only from the thread on which it was created. Attempting to
>   access it from another thread throws an InvalidOperationException. The
>   Dispatcher.Invoke and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke methods provide support
>   for marshalling to the correct thread.
>
> When their IsFrozen property is true, Freezable objects are
>   free-threaded. For more information, see Freezable Objects Overview.

Comment: Ahhh Thank you. Since I don't need to modify my `GeometryGroup` once it is created, this works perfectly for me.